# How do I delete XML tags from XML document in java

Tags: java, xml

How do I delete XML tags from XML document in java?

For Example, I have the following XML:

```
<root>
  <item>
     <code>100001</code>
     <price>456</price>
     <name>ABC</name>
</item>
  <item>
     <code>100002</code>
     <price>123</price>
     <name>DEF</name>
</item>
  <item>
     <code>100003</code>
     <price>887</price>
     <name>XYZ</name>
</item>
</root>
```

I want to delete the price tag from the XML and produce the XML in the following manner:

```
<root>
      <item>
         <code>100001</code>
         <name>ABC</name>
    </item>
      <item>
         <code>100002</code>
         <name>DEF</name>
    </item>
      <item>
         <code>100003</code>
         <name>XYZ</name>
    </item>
    </root>
```

Additionally the requirement is such that the XML tags can change as I get this information from a webservice which can change the information it sends.

Comment: writing your own parser for that purpose would take about 10 mins max

Comment: What mode you want to use? DOM, OM, JAXB or custom parser?

Comment: I don't recommend ever writing your own parser for XML, as it is trickier than you might think.  If you're really dealing with a tightly constrained profile of XML, however, then maybe it makes sense to do so.  Myself, I'd be inclined to do this kind of job with an XSLT transform.  Java has XSLT support, and the needed transform would be pretty simple.

Answer (score 1):

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class JAXBExample {
    static Root root = new Root();
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
        File file = new File("C:\\file.xml");
        File file1 = new File("C:\\result.xml");
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);

        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        Root rootEle = (Root) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);

        ArrayList<item> itemList =new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < rootEle.getItemList().size() ; i++){
            item itemLocal = new item();
            itemLocal.setCode(rootEle.getItemList().get(i).getCode());
            itemLocal.setName(rootEle.getItemList().get(i).getName());
            itemList.add(itemLocal);
        }
        root.setItemList(itemList);
        Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

        // output pretty printed
        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(root, file1);
        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(root, System.out);

    }
}
```

Root class:

```
import org.apache.activemq.kaha.impl.data.Item;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import java.util.ArrayList;

@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
public class Root {

    public ArrayList<item> getItem() {
        return itemList;
    }

    public void setItem(ArrayList<item> item) {
        this.itemList = item;
    }

    private ArrayList<item> itemList;

}
```

Item calss:

```
public class item {
    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {

        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    private String code;
    private String name;
}
```

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

As commented, consider XSLT that runs the [Identity Transform](http://www.usingxml.com/Transforms/XslIdentity) and an empty template on the node you wish to remove. No `for` loops, `if` logic, or use of data structures (e.g., arraylist, hashmaps) needed for this solution.

As information, [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/) is a special purpose language (sibling to XPath) designed to transform xml files into other xml, html, even text files (csv/txt). General purpose languages like Java, PHP, Python, and others maintain libraries to run XSLT 1.0 scripts and can even call external dedicated XSLT processors like libxslt/Saxon. Additionally, XSLT scripts are themselves well-formed XML files and can be parsed from file or string for any dynamic needs.

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl script to be parsed from file in Java below)*

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- Identity Transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Removes all price tags -->
  <xsl:template match="price"/>

</xsl:transform>
```

**Java**

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class CourseList {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException,
                                                  SAXException, 
                                                  ParserConfigurationException,
                                                  TransformerException {    
        // LOAD XML AND XSL DOCUMENTS
        String inputXML = "C:\\Path\\To\\Input.xml";
        String xslFile =  "C:\\Path\\To\\XSLTScript.xsl";
        String outputXML =  "C:\\Path\\To\\Output.xml";                                   

        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();            
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse (new File(inputXML));
        Source xslt = new StreamSource(new File(xslFile)); 

        // XSLT TRANSFORMATION WITH PRETTY PRINT
        TransformerFactory prettyPrint = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = prettyPrint.newTransformer(xslt);

        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.STANDALONE, "yes");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");                        

        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(outputXML));        
        transformer.transform(source, result);
    }
}
```